# Adding new attributes in Spark nested Array JSON

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to add new attribute to a nested Array Object using Spark and running into issues while setting the value for it using the parent attributes.

Here is the Json structure I have

```html
{"docType":"Test2","id": "126","attr1": "testString4","attr2": [{ "innerAttr1":"abc","innerAttr2": "Test1232"}],"date": "2020-09-21T22:35:00"}
{"docType":"Test2","id": "127","attr1": "testString5","attr2": [{ "innerAttr1":"def","innerAttr2": "Test1234"}],"date": "2021-09-21T22:35:00"}
```

And i want to add an Attribute "Id" to each element of "attr2". And it should be a concatenation of parent Id and self attribute. So the final doc should be

```html
{"docType":"Test2","id": "126","attr1": "testString4","attr2": [{ "innerAttr1":"abc","innerAttr2": "Test1232","id":"126_Test1232"}],"date": "2020-09-21T22:35:00"}
{"docType":"Test2","id": "127","attr1": "testString5","attr2": [{ "innerAttr1":"def","innerAttr2": "Test1234","id":"127_Test1234"}],"date": "2021-09-21T22:35:00"}
```

Here is the Spark Code i am using

```
dataSet.withColumn("attr2",
  transform($"attr2",
    attr2 => attr2.withField("id",
      concat(
        $"id",
        lit("_"),
        $"attr2.innerAttr2"
      )
    )
  )
)
```

When i try to run it i am getting the following Error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'concat(Id, '_', attr2.`innerAttr2`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function concat should all be the same type, but it's [string, string, array<string>];
```

I am unable to figure out why **attr2.`innerAttr2`** is an Array of Strings rather than String.

Thanks
Sateesh